# How to extract data one by one from the array in a simple way and pass it to the constructor

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, list

I am new to python, here is the first part of my graduation project. I want to extract data from MySql 'insert' statements

```
                    if tableName == 'accounts':
                    a = Account(rm_apostrophe(slippedMsgs[0]), rm_apostrophe(slippedMsgs[1]),
                                rm_apostrophe(slippedMsgs[2]))
                        print(a.account_id, a.account_name, a.customer_code)
                    Accounts.append(a)
```

In the code above, `Account` is a class used to save data, `rm_apostrophe` is a method for handle strings.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, account_id, account_name, customer_code):
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.account_name = account_name
        self.customer_code = customer_code

    def rm_apostrophe(raw_data):
        if raw_data is None or raw_data == "Null":
            return None
        elif raw_data.startswith("'"):
            return raw_data[1:-1]
        else:
            return raw_data
```

Account is a simple method with only three attributes, so there is no problem with writing this way.
But I have another class named `Ticket` with 73 attributes, which means that I have to do `rm_apostrophe(slippedMsgs[x])` 73 times in

```
t = Ticket(rm_apostrophe(slippedMsgs[0]), rm_apostrophe(slippedMsgs[1]),
                                rm_apostrophe(slippedMsgs[2])...etc)
```

I guess there should be an easier way to help me pass in these parameters, maybe I need to modify the constructor. Hope someone can help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to create the list of arguments:
`args = [rm_apostrophe(x) for x in slippedMsgs]` 
Then you can pass these arguments using 
`t = Ticket(*args)`
The * before the `args` passes every item in the list as an argument to `Ticket`

Comment: If you were helped by this answer, please consider marking it as accepted.